# Load order in XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, component-based

I am wondering whether the is a mechanism to manually control the call-order of

```
void Game.LoadContent()
```

as it is the case with

```
void Game.Draw(GameTime gt)
```

by setting

```
int DrawableGameComponent.DrawOrder
```

?

- except the order that results from adding components to the `Game.Components` container and
- maybe there exists something similar with `Game.Update(GameTime gt)` ?

**UPDATE**

To exemplify my issue consider you have several game components which do depends to each other regarding their instantiation. All are inherited from `DrawableGameComponent`.

Now suppose that in one of these components you are loading a `Model` from the games content pipeline and add it to some static container in order to provide access to it for other game components.

```
public override LoadContent() {

    // ...

    Model m = _contentManager.Load<Model>(@"content/myModel");

    // GameComponents is a static class with an accessible list where game components reside.
    GameComponents.AddCompnent(m);

   // ...

}
```

Now it's easy to imagine that this components load method has to precede other game components that do want to access the model m in their own load method.

Comment: I think the different Components and their LoadContent() methods should be designed so, that they don't depend on each other or the order you call them. Maybe you can edit your answer with an example where (you think) you need to play around with the load order.

Comment: @Marton Well, you are certainly right - avoiding dependencies is always preferable. Nevertheless in my experience the more game components you have in your program the more difficult it gets to decrease or avoid coupling/dependencies. I will add an example to my post ...

Answer (score 1):

> Now suppose that in one of these components you are loading a Model
>   from the games content pipeline and add it to some static container in
>   order to provide access to it for other game components.

if other components need the model, they should get it throught the content manager...

in case a component need to know what model has other compnent, maybe you need a post initialization method where it succeed

```
public void Initialize()    {...}
public void PostInitialize() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Game.LoadContent()` method will (in the default template) have the line `base.LoadContent();` in it. That will call the `LoadContent()` methods of all your `DrawableGameComponent`s.

If you have content that must be loaded before some other `Component` tries to access it, then you can simply load it in the `Game.LoadContent()` method, before calling `base.LoadContent();`

However, I'm still unsure why you need to access the loaded content from other components before the `Update()` - `Draw()` cycle starts.

Comment: This is subtly incorrect. `DrawableGameComponent.LoadContent` is not called from `Game.LoadContent`, but from `DrawableGameComponent.Initialize` (which itself gets called from `Game.Initialize` during startup; or when the component is added, after startup).